# Rails utilize a function in both ActionController and ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller

We have a generic logging function that is in application.rb under our controllers. This function is not found by active job though (I'm assuming as because our email jobs extend ActiveJob::Base vs our controllers that reference ActionController which then references ActionController::Base)

Where would the right place be to put the logging function so we can keep are code as DRY as possible?

Answer (score 1):

So after some talking with others the best course was decided by using the lib folder and creating a module within it.

We created a folder called trackers and a file called tracker.rb in it. Below is a basic snippet of what it looks like

```
module Trackers

  module_function 

  mattr_accessor :controller

  def track_action(event_name, event_params)

    event_params["time"]    ||= Time.now.utc.to_i

    # Controller scope only - this only gets executed if the function is called via a controller vs an ActiveJob
    if controller
      event_params["controller_name"]  ||=   controller_name
      event_params["action_name"]      ||=   action_name
    end

#Other stuff redacted

  end
end
```

Within the application.rb file we modified the code to include the folder as such:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
 #{config.root}/lib/
 #{config.root}/lib/trackers/
)
```

Within a method in a Controller or ActiveJob it is called as such -

```
  Trackers.track_action("eventName", {
    "someVar"     => "someValue",
  })
```

Another alternative was using a model but I felt this is much more of a lib function - we may turn it into a gem later on.

Hope this helps others in the future.